# hide error on form resubmit using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

If the user does't fill in all the fields properly, an error block shows up with all the errors. At the moment if they click submit again, the error message stays there while the little loader spins round and submits the form again. I tried to hide the error message but it hid the message even on initial submit which isn't right. It just needs to hide the error message if it is visible.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "process.php",
    data: str,
    beforeSend: function() {
        $("#contact-submit").hide();
        $("#loading").show(); 
    },
    success: function(response) {
        $('#error').html(response);
        if (!response || response.length == 0 || response.indexOf("Your message was sent") >= 0)
        $("#contact-form").hide();
                $("#contact-submit").show();
                $("#loading").hide();
```

This is my new solution:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process.php",
            data: str,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $("#contact-submit").hide();
                 $("#loading").show(); 
                  },
          success: function(response) {
    $('#error').html(response);
   if (!response || response.length == 0 || response.indexOf("Your message was sent") >= 0)
        $("#hfarm-contact-form").hide();
                $("#contact-submit").show();
                $("#loading").hide();
              $('#error').fadeIn().html(response);  
                          setTimeout(function(){  
                               $('#error').fadeOut("Slow");  
                          }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [jQuery data](https://api.jquery.com/data/) to store a variale associated to contact-submit element:

- If this value is true: another submit is impossible because it's necessary
  to wait for the previous ajax to finish
- If, instead this value is false a new ajax call can be done

Moreover, you may use the

```
complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus ) {
```

to reset values like show and hiding elements plus the value of this new variable.

The delay function is only for snippet purpose to slow the execution.
My snippet:

```js
function delay(ms) {
  var cur_d = new Date();
  var cur_ticks = cur_d.getTime();
  var ms_passed = 0;
  while(ms_passed < ms) {
    var d = new Date();  // Possible memory leak?
    var ticks = d.getTime();
    ms_passed = ticks - cur_ticks;
    // d = null;  // Prevent memory leak?
  }
}

$(function () {
  // Initialize....
  $("#loading").hide();
  $('#contact-submit').data('isInprogress', false);

  // on input submit click....
  $('#contact-submit').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    // before to start anything: check form and if error
    // stop (return immediately).
    // you cannot stop  the submit inside the ajax call.
    // do your control here.....
    
    
    // after continue..... taking in account an ajax call is asyncronous
    
    
    
    var isInprogress = $('#contact-submit').data('isInprogress');
    if(isInprogress === true) {
      alert('Already loading...');
      return;
    }
    $('#contact-submit').data('isInprogress', true);
    var str = '';
    $.ajax({
      dataType: 'json',
      url: 'https://api.github.com/users',
      data: str,
      beforeSend: function() {
        $("#contact-submit").hide();
        $("#loading").show();
      },
      success: function(data, jqXHR ) {
        var a = data;
      },
      complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus ) {
        delay(2000);
        $('#contact-submit').data('isInprogress', false);
        $("#contact-submit").show();
        $("#loading").hide();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="loading">loading.......</div>
<form id="frm">
    <input id="contact-submit" type="submit" value="Click Me To get Data with Ajax">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is rather advanced for me. Is there not an easier way to achieve the error message disappearing if the user presses submit again after the initial submit? Also, it looks like you removed the code that hides the entire form after successful submission ( I think?)

Comment: Okay, sure. I will have to wrap my head around it and see how far I get. Will post back once I have made progress (or not) ;)

Comment: I have edited my initial post and would like to choose my answer as the one that is best for me. Unless of course someone thinks it is incorrect or doesn't work course.

Comment: Sorry, I don't fully understand your comment. Are you saying that my code is in the wrong place?

Comment: @Jonathan Yes, I assume your check code is in the wrong place.